# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sellerLogIn()

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass the variables to the function where the actual assigning of values to Session variables are, but it gives me an error where it says the function is undefined

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=$_POST['un'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $uType=$_POST['logn'];

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","bns_admin","hellobns","buynsave") or die('<script src="Connectfail.js"></script>');

    if($uType="seller"){
        $query="SELECT * FROM sellers WHERE sellerUserName='".$username."'";
        $passQuery="SELECT * FROM sellers WHERE sellerPassWD='".$pass."'";
        sellerLogIn($conn,$passQuery,$query,$username,$uType);
    }

function sellerLogIn($conn,$passQuery,$query,$username,$uType){
        $result=$conn->query($query);
        $passResult=$conn->query($passQuery);

        if($result && $passResult){
            $getIDQ="SELECT sellerID FROM sellers WHERE sellerUserName='".$username."'";
            $getID=$conn->query($getIDQ);

            $_SESSION['usertype']=$uType;
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            $_SESSION['sellerID']=$getID;
        }

        else
            echo '<script src="logDeb.js"></script>';



    }
```

Comment: Take your function declaration out of the IF block. At the top of your code should work.

Comment: I think that's probably because I only partially copied the code. I just snipped the parts that are directly connected to the error

Comment: So are you certain that the function is declared outside of another code block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more specific to @aynber's point in the comments: [User-defined functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) contained within blocks will not exist until they have been reached by the program's execution. Since your `function` exists within a block, and the code that references it is *before* the function has been declared, you'll get errors relating to an `undefined function`.

The solution is to re-factor your program to move the function declaration higher up within your block, or push the function's declaration outside to the root level of your program so that it will be immediately available on your program's start.